# how to use Tesseract.recognize in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, tesseract

I want to make an OCR program but I fund some problems during the declaration of 'Tesseract.recognize' method

here is my code :

```
const express = require('express');

const fs= require('fs');

const multer = require('multer');

const Tesseract = require('Tesseract.js');

const app = express();

// app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

const PORT = process.env.PORT | 5000;   

var Storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, callback) {
      callback(null, 'images')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, callback) {
      callback(null, file.orignalname);
    }
});
var upload = multer({
 storage: Storage 
}).array('image', 3);
//route
app.post('/', (req, res) => {});

app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.file);
    upload(req, res , err => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.send('somthing went wrong');
        }
        return res.send('file uploaded successfully');
    });
});

var image = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/images/cv.jpg', 
    {
        encoding:null
    });

Tesseract.recognize(image)
    .progress(function(p) {
        console.log('progress', p);
    })
    .then(function(result) {
        res.send('result', result);
    });

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('Server running on PORT ${PORT}')
});
```

and this is my terminal result:

```
.progress(function(p) {
     ^

TypeError: Tesseract.recognize(...).progress is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\de\Desktop\MR.Azmani Project\ANGULAR\ocr\server.js:46:6)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

and this it what is the result how should look like in the treminal during the process
[image]

and this is the final result in the termilal

[image]

thank you

Comment: What version of tesseract.js are you on? `.progress` was removed in version 2.

Comment: I m using version '2.1.4'
so now I should install a lower version right!?

Comment: Yes — see my answer, I included some links to docs and examples if you want to move to v2

Answer (score 2):

`.progress` was removed in version 2 of tesseract.js (there's a blog post about that [here](https://medium.com/@jeromewus/why-i-refactor-tesseract-js-v2-50f750a9cfe2). Version one is still on Github [here](https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js/tree/support/1.x), and probably still works, so you can `npm i tesseract.js@1.0.19` to get the behavior you're expecting, or see the docs and [examples](https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js/blob/master/examples/node/recognize.js) for the current version to get your code updated for v2.